# Collision detection for multiplayer game with MatterJS

Tags: physics, javascript, movement, collision-resolution

We are developing JavaScript multiplayer top down game where characters can move freely and collide with each other. We are rather weak at mathematics and physics, luckily we don't need much, just some basic movement & collision mechanics.

After a lot of struggle and failures with custom collision mechanics we decided to use [MatterJS](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js) library. That works like a charm when character collides with static object (like a wall). However when two characters meet, they basically bounce off each other.

We use simple circle based body with `frictionAir` and `inverseInertia` set to 0. There is a [lot of other properties](http://brm.io/matter-js-docs/classes/Body.html), but we are rather clueless how the bounce off actually happens. Anybody can point us in the right direction please?

Comment: What do you wish happened instead of the objects bouncing? Do you want a completely [inelastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision)?